# How to print numbers which are below left diagonal in matrix?

Tags: java

```java
for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) 
{
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) 
    {
        System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The above code is not able to print numbers which are below the left diagonal. For a 3x3 matrix my code is printing:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

OUTPUT :

```
4  5 
7  8
```

Desired output:

```
4
7 8
```

Comment: Think about it. How many numbers per line have to be printed? First row, none. Second row, one. Third row, two. And so on, depending on the size of the matrix. So, with that in mind, try to alter your loop variables. Keep in mind not to use fixed numbers, but to loop according to your matrix size.

Comment: @maloomeister Please suggest code for 5*5 matrix.

Comment: If the matrix always has the **same** amount of rows an columns, you can simply print `n` numbers (starting with `n=0`) for each row, starting from the first one and incrementing `n++` for each row.

Comment: The second condition should be j < i.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an if statment like this :

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        if (i>j) {
        System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Or better you could do :

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
     for(int j=0;i>j;j++) {
          System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: above code is suitable for all size of matrix like 2*2, 3*3, 4*4?

Comment: The secod part yes

Comment: @manu I did some edits. Check again. It works perfect on me

Comment: Altough working, your solution prints an empty first line.

Comment: @Glains Yes that's because at the first loop j is equal to i so nothing to print and prints an empty line. If you dont whant that you coud add an if (i!=0) before the empty line

Comment: @manu Please consider accepting my answer if that was what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve this depending on the matrix size is

```
final int matrixSize = 7; // your matrix size
for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++ i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++ j) System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: You solution prints all number in one line. OP requires the numbers for each row to be on separate lines.